# DataGrid v5 migration: columns are hidden despite hide: true

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm migrating our app to v5 of MUI including datagrid tables.  I have a weird problem where even though the columns array says `hide: true` for particular columns, it's still being shown.  There's some dynamic bits with custom views for the table that depend on prop values, but this all worked in v4.

I even log the columns value and it shows `hide: true`, but as you can see in the screenshot, it's not hidden.

The full code is here https://github.com/stbenjam/sippy/blob/mui-v5/sippy-ng/src/tests/TestTable.js.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Oh man, I accidentally installed data-grid v6 instead of v5 and hide is gone. I knew hide was deprecated in 5 but didn't plan to handle that yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).